# Can I use different selection comparisons based on a passed value in SQL?

Tags: sql

I wasn't really sure of the best wording for the question but here is my dilemma:

I am passing a value to a sql query as `@district`. This value may be the exact district but it also has the possibility of being a value that should create a set of multiple districts. So if I pass `002` I want the `WHERE` clause to say `I.Offense_Tract = @district`. If I pass `Other` I want the `WHERE` clause to say `I.Offense_Tract in ()`. What I am trying to do is something like:

```
AND
CASE
   WHEN @district = "Other" THEN I.Offense_Tract in ('BAR','COL','GER','MEM','MIL','JAIL','JAILEAST','SCCC','1USD','2USD')
ELSE I.Offense_Tract = @district
END
```

But this doesn't work. The problem, restated, is if the value passed is anything other than `Other`, I just want it to be =. If `Other` is passed, I want it to be `IN`.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `CASE` expression.
You can apply this logic with operators `AND` and `OR`:

```
AND (
      (@district = 'Other' AND I.Offense_Tract IN ('BAR','COL','GER','MEM','MIL','JAIL','JAILEAST','SCCC','1USD','2USD'))
      OR
      (@district <> 'Other' AND I.Offense_Tract = @district)
    )
```

Note that, in databases like MySql, Postgresql and SQLite, your code would work as it is.

Comment: Thank you.  This was what I was looking for. I normally pride myself on the logic but for some reason, this evaded me.